# Jekyll Kramdown # (H1) not formatting as heading

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, jekyll, github-pages, kramdown

I am new to Jekyll and kramdown, so I might need help asking my question.

I am having trouble with the H1 heading: so the following in a post (markdown file [download here](https://ufile.io/ii4nhxaq)):

```markdown
# H1 looks like this
## H2 looks like this
### H3 looks like this
#### H4 looks like this
##### H5 looks like this
###### H6 looks like this
Normal text looks like this
```

Generates this:

[image]

H2-H6 look fine, but I don't know what is wrong with H1, but I would like it to format correctly.

---

`Gemfile`

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll", ">= 3.8.5"

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
  gem "jekyll-paginate", "~> 1.1.0"
  gem "jekyll-sitemap"
end

platforms :mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby do
  gem "tzinfo", "~> 1.2"
  gem "tzinfo-data"
end

gem "wdm", ">= 0.1.1" if Gem.win_platform?

gem "webrick"
```

`_config.yml` file

```yaml
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
permalink: pretty

highlighter: rouge
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  auto_ids: true
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

The HTML is like this. Full [HTML file download](https://ufile.io/e0v2ik5v)

```
<h1 id="h1-looks-like-this">H1 looks like this</h1>
<h2 id="h2-looks-like-this">H2 looks like this</h2>
<h3 id="h3-looks-like-this">H3 looks like this</h3>
<h4 id="h4-looks-like-this">H4 looks like this</h4>
<h5 id="h5-looks-like-this">H5 looks like this</h5>
<h6 id="h6-looks-like-this">H6 looks like this</h6>
<p>Normal text looks like this</p>
```

`main.css` file is [here](https://github.com/karpathy/karpathy.github.io/blob/master/css/main.css). `h1` appears several times, excerpted here:

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-size: 100%; font-weight: 400; }

...

.home h1 { margin-bottom: 25px; }

...

.post-header h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: -1.75px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}

...

.post-content h1,
.post-content h2,
.post-content h3,
.post-content h4,
.post-content h5,
.post-content h6 {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 40px 0 20px;

...

  .post-header h1 { font-size: 36px; }
  .post-content h2 { font-size: 28px; }
  .post-content h3 { font-size: 22px; }
  .post-content h4 { font-size: 18px; }
  .post-content blockquote { padding-left: 10px; }
  .post-content ul,
  .post-content ol { padding-left: 10px; }
}
```

Comment: Look at the source html in your browser inspectyor. Is the <h1> tag in the source? If so, you need to change your CSS file. If not I'm not sure why not

Comment: I have added the CSS and HTML. I don't see anything strange in it that explains the issue.

Comment: can you link the sample page as well?

Comment: I have added download links to the HTML and markdown files. (I assume that is what you meant)

Comment: The `post.html` layout contains: `<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>`, which is rendered properly as a h1 heading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in the css, which specifies things like

```
.post-content h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: -1.25px;
}
```

for H2, H3, H4, but not for H1.

Just add `font-size: 40px;` inside .post-content H1 in your CSS file and you'll be fine.

I suggest learning to use your browser's inspector to find problems like this. Just right-click on an element in your page and then select "inspect". Then go from there.